# How to avoid duplicate insertUI in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In this code

```
if (interactive()) {
  # Define UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("add", "Add UI"),
    actionButton("remove", "Remove UI"),
    tags$div(id = "add")
  )

  # Server logic
  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # adding UI
    observeEvent(input$add, {
      insertUI(
        selector = "#add",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = 
          div(
            textInput("txt", "Insert some text"),
            id="textinput"
          )
      )
    })

    # removing UI
    observeEvent(input$remove, {
      removeUI(selector = "#textinput")
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

I want dynamic UI to appear only **once**. **Regardless of the number of button "add" presses.**

However, after you click "Remove UI" button, you should be able to add the dynamic interface again (also once)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `conditionalPanel` and `observe`.

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
  # Define UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("add", "Add UI"),
    actionButton("remove", "Remove UI"),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.add > 0", 
                     uiOutput("textbox"))
  )

  # Server logic
  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # adding UI
    observe({
      if (!is.null(input$add)) {
        output$textbox <- renderUI({
          div(
            textInput("txt", "Insert some text"),
            id="textinput"
          )
        })
      }
    })

    # removing UI
    observeEvent(input$remove, {
      removeUI(selector = "#textinput")
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

**EDIT** - without `conditionalPanel`.

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
  # Define UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("add", "Add UI"),
    actionButton("remove", "Remove UI"),
    uiOutput("textbox"))


  # Server logic
  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # adding UI
    observeEvent(input$add, 
      output$textbox <- renderUI({
        div(
          textInput("txt", "Insert some text"),
          id="textinput"
          )
      })

    )

    # removing UI
    observeEvent(input$remove, {
      removeUI(selector = "#textinput")
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: It works, but speaking honestly, I don't understand how :) After the first click on "add" button `input.add` becomes always >0 and `conditionalPanel` shoud be always visible. But anyway, proposed code solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yea,the button will always be there until the remove button is pressed. And the button will re-appear (triggered by the `observe`) when add button is clicked.

Comment: I've just posted second solution which doesnt rely on `conditinalPanel`.